# I am not able to add new paragraph in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a description to my page where I am using a heading and general description.

Instead of forming a new paragraph, the description is appearing immediately after the heading.

Below is the html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <h1>General Description</h1>
    <p class="lead">Summary of company..!!</p>
```

Comment: Read the Bootstrap docs *"only columns may be immediate children of rows"*

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>General Description</h1>
                <p class="lead">Summary of company..!!</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Yo can change "col-md-12". Because Bootstrap grid system is 12 column. If you change this content area and sidebar;

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h1>General Description</h1>
                <p class="lead">Summary of company..!!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                Sidebar Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you want to make centered;

just add `<center></center>`

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <center>
                    <h1>General Description</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Summary of company..!!</p>
                </center>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                Sidebar Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked for new paragraph but now my text is not centred

Comment: I'm added the code to my answer.

Comment: The `<center>` tag will work, but it's deprecated and not HTML5 compliant

Comment: Thanks. It worked completely fine. :)